# how to choose android system platform on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and when I was downloading Android 4.4.2 (API 19).

I noticed Android 4.4W (API 20) has already been installed by default.

How do I make sure Android Studio uses 4.4.2 and not 4.4W?

Is there a way to check which SDK Android Studio is currently selecting?

I'm using Mac o/s if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what version of API to use during a new project creation.

For existing project: *File > Project Structure*. Select the appropriate module on the left pane, then open *Properties* tab. *Compile Sdk Version* will be there.
Another option is to edit `<project_folder>\app\build.gradle` file manually.

Answer (score 0):

1- Right click on the project's folder >> under Resources - Android.

2- you will find the current platform "checked".